# Modules not Found Py2app

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pyinstaller, py2app

Compiling my app on "alias mode"  `$ python setup.py py2app -A` and opening the .app works fine, but trying to compile the deployable version `$ python setup.py py2app` crashes after trying to open the app.
I'm using MacOsCatalina , python 3.7 and pycharm

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

    APP = ['test.py']
    DATA_FILES = []

    OPTIONS = {

        'argv_emulation': True,
        'includes': ['requests'],
        'packages': ['requests', 'rumps']

    }

    setup(
        app=APP,
        name='TestApp',
        data_files=DATA_FILES,
        options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
        setup_requires=['py2app'],
    )
```

What Console shows after running `$ python setup.py py2app`

```
Modules not found (conditional imports):
 * Cookie (requests.compat)
 * OpenSSL.crypto (urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl)
 * Queue (urllib3.util.queue)
 * StringIO (pkg_resources._vendor.six, requests.compat, urllib3.packages.six)
 * com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * com.sun.jna (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * com.sun.jna.platform (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * cookielib (requests.compat)
 * cryptography.x509.extensions (urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl)
 * urllib2 (requests.compat)
 * urlparse (requests.compat)
 * win32com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * win32com.shell (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to make a barebones version with rumps as the only imported module in test.py , here's the crash log:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
```

Comment: Are you using a venv?

Comment: @NoahBroyles Yes i'm using pycharm

Comment: yes, using MacOSCatalina

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded setuptools from version 46 to 44, `pip install setuptools==44.0.0`

latest version causes issues with py2app and pyinstaller.